# Controller Routing & Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After following the RoR [getting started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) tutorial, I added another model as:

```
$ rails g model Category name:string wdate:date
```

I added the line `resources :category` to my routes.rb file, and copy+pasted the initial Posts controller, changing names from Post to Category and Posts to Categories.

I did similarly with the index, form, new, and edit views.

Now, `localhost:3000/category` gives me an empty list of categories, and `/category/new` gives me an input form.  Upon submission, however, I get

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches [POST] "/categories"
>
> Try running rake routes for more information on available routes

Running `rake routes` as suggested shows that I have:

```
POST   /category(.:format)          category#create
```

Why is the form submitting to the wrong address?  The only area where I put in the term "categories" was for the variable name in the #index handler, so I don't understand why the form target is `/categories`.  Do I have to explicitly set the path as `/category` for creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `resources :category` line inside `config/routes.rb` should be `resources :categories`.

When you're doing `resources`, you should always use the pluralized name of the resource so that Rails will automatically singularize it for member routing helpers of that resource, such as `edit_category_path(category)`.

It will then use the plural form in routes for collections, like the `form_for`. Because the object is new, the form will issue a POST request to `/categories` with the form data.